# Возможно ли в datagrid вывести подстроки?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

У меня есть коллекция объектов, каждый объект имеет в себе коллекцию других объектов. Возможно ли эту коллекцию вывести в DataGrid.
Мой код:
//ViewModel

```
public class ObladnanViewModel
        {
            public ObservableCollection<ObladnanModel> Collection { get; set; }
            public ObservableCollection<ElectromotoruModel> Electromotors { get;   set; }

            public ObladnanViewModel()
            {
                Electromotors =new ObservableCollection<ElectromotoruModel>()
                {
                    new ElectromotoruModel(){Id= 1,Marka = "AO2",Name = "Main"},
                    new ElectromotoruModel(){Id=2,Marka = "4",Name = "Main"},
                    new ElectromotoruModel(){Id=3,Marka = "AO2",Name = "Main"}
                };
                Collection=new ObservableCollection<ObladnanModel>()
                {
                    new ObladnanModel(1,"Obl1",Electromotors),
                    new ObladnanModel(2,"Obl2",Electromotors)
                };
            }
        }
```

Класс ElectromotoruModel:

```
public class ElectromotoruModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Marka { get; set; }
    }

public class ObladnanModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ElectromotoruModel> Elektromotors { get; set; }

        public ObladnanModel(int id, string name, ObservableCollection<ElectromotoruModel> electromotors)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Elektromotors = electromotors;
        }
    }
```

И пробивал так XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Margin="24,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=TwoWay }" Width="462" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"  SelectionMode="Single" RenderTransformOrigin="0.413,0.626"  >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Id,Mode=TwoWay }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Motors" Binding="{Binding Elektromotors ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Но в Motors выводит просто пустую строку.
Возможно ли сделать так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ответ не решил мою проблему.

Comment: Обидно. Если у вас получилось найти решение самостоятельно, пожалуйста, опубликуйте его в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Пока что не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Правда не в DataGrid а в ListBox но и так пойдет) 
Моя ViewModel:

```
 public class ObladnanViewModel
{

    public ObservableCollection<ObladnanModel> Collection { get; set; }

    public ObladnanViewModel()
    {
        Collection=new ObservableCollection<ObladnanModel>()
        {
            new ObladnanModel(1,"Obl1",new ObservableCollection<ElectromotoruModel>()
        {
                  new ElectromotoruModel(){Id= 1,Marka = "AO2",Name = "Main"},
                  new ElectromotoruModel(){Id=2,Marka = "4",Name = "Main"},
                  new ElectromotoruModel(){Id=3,Marka = "AO2",Name = "Main"}}),

            new ObladnanModel(2,"Obl2",new ObservableCollection<ElectromotoruModel>()
        {
                  new ElectromotoruModel(){Id= 1,Marka = "36",Name = "Main"},
                  new ElectromotoruModel(){Id=6,Marka = "4",Name = "Vent"},
                  new ElectromotoruModel(){Id=3,Marka = "AO6",Name = "cooling"},
                  new ElectromotoruModel(){Id = 4,Marka = "C03",Name = "movement table"}}
            )
        };
    }
}
```

Код Xaml:

```
                        </Grid>
                        <Border Grid.Row="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                                <ItemsPresenter />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="noStyleToListboxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Width="501"></ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>



<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="197*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="202*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListBox MaxHeight="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrushOpacity}" Style="{StaticResource calcyListbox}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource noStyleToListboxItem}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,42,11,10">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="127*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="144*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="90*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="99*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="41*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="50,18,53,17" Width="24"/>
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                    <ListBox Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" Background="{StaticResource customBlueBrushOpacity}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Elektromotors}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" BorderBrush="Black" Margin="50,-2,-60,0" Grid.Column="1" RenderTransformOrigin="1.857,0.35"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Marka}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="40" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Margin="113.5,0,-116,0" Width="52"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

В английской литературе это называется [RowDetails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903938(v=vs.95).aspx). Вполне логично - детали строки. так вот, вам нужен RowDetailsTemplate. Подозреваю, что в вашем случае, вы хотите в качестве подстроки использовать ещё одну таблицу с несколькими колонками.

```
<Grid>
   <DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="131" Margin="24,26,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, Mode=TwoWay }" Width="462" SelectionChanged="DataGrid_SelectionChanged" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" RenderTransformOrigin="0.413,0.626">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="id" Binding="{Binding Id,Mode=TwoWay }" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name,Mode=TwoWay}" />
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Motors" Binding="{Binding Electromotors ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
      </DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
               <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Elektromotors}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                  <DataGrid.Columns>
                     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
                     <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Marka}" Header="Marka" />
                  </DataGrid.Columns>
               </DataGrid>
            </DockPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
   </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это должна бить плоская datagrid как на рисунке. Возможно ли так?

Comment: На самом деле объекты ObladnanModel имеют разное количество объектов  ElectromotoruModel.